# React Native with Supabase Auth Error [AuthRetryableFetchError]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, supabase, supabase-js

I got this error with Expo and Supabase auth (email & pass), Anyone can help?
Error shown as below:

My login code

```js
const onLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
        email: "example8@gmail.com",
        password: "123456",
      });

      if (error) throw error;
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Response error:

```json
[AuthRetryableFetchError: {"type":"default","status":502,"ok":false,"statusText":"","headers":{"map":{"access-control-allow-origin":"*","alt-svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=86400","cf-cache-status":"DYNAMIC","cf-ray":"803c5fb7bfdb40da-SIN","content-length":"75","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","date":"Sat, 09 Sep 2023 03:34:10 GMT","sb-gateway-version":"1","server":"cloudflare","strict-transport-security":"max-age=2592000; includeSubDomains","vary":"Accept-Encoding","via":"kong/2.8.1","x-kong-proxy-latency":"12","x-kong-upstream-latency":"1"}},"url":"https://ffdrqqyghmvdfoosjpej.supabase.co/auth/v1/token?grant_type=password","bodyUsed":false,"_bodyInit":{"_data":{"size":75,"offset":0,"blobId":"D0B50075-9684-4C29-8DF0-7F8E00B97235","type":"application/json","name":"token.json","__collector":{}}},"_bodyBlob":{"_data":{"size":75,"offset":0,"blobId":"D0B50075-9684-4C29-8DF0-7F8E00B97235","type":"application/json","name":"token.json","__collector":{}}}}]
```

Result should be user/session json object

Comment: That sounds like something's wrong with your project. Can you please reach out to support via the Dashboard: https://supabase.com/dashboard/support/new ?